# What is the difference between delimiters in interface?

Tags: typescript

In a codebase I am working on, I notice that two kind of interface are used:

One use semi-colon:

```
interface LabelledValue {
    label: string;
    value: string;
}
```

The second is comma based:

```
interface LabelledValue {
    label: string,
    value: string
}
```

I generate those interface in JS and outputs are identical. The official documentation use the first kind of interface: [Handbook Interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html).

Is there a difference between both? Is this just an example of two syntax for one solution?

Comment: There is no difference between the two syntax styles, one is more object literal like the other more class like. I can't find any documentation for the rationale, but 99.999% sure there is no difference

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir at least if there is a difference, I cant find it either :)

Comment: The reason for style with `;` is to support copy paste style. Declare your interface... copy it and change the header `class LabelledValueImpl implements LabelledValue {` while next lines stay the same.. so sugary.. just a sugar for us

Answer (score -4):

An interface is a contract: The person writing the interface says, "hey, I accept things looking that way", and the person using the interface says "OK, the class I write looks that way".

An interface is an empty shell. There are only the signatures of the methods, which implies that the methods do not have a body. The interface can't do anything. It's just a pattern.

For example (pseudo code):

I say all motor vehicles should look like this:

```
interface MotorVehicle
{
    void run();

    int getFuel();
}
```

My team mate complies and writes vehicle looking that way

```
class Car implements MotorVehicle
{

    int fuel;

    void run()
    {
        print("Wrroooooooom");
    }

    int getFuel()
    {
        return this.fuel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know what is interface. I am looking to find if there is a difference between typescript double syntax.